# React Search Bar - runs twice after each search

Tags: reactjs, graphql, strapi

I am trying to implement a search bar in React but I need some help. My functions works partially :D

The functions runs twice after clicking Submit. First time gets all the data and then gets the data that has been filtered. I don't know what am I missing. If you could help, I would owe you a lot!

Thank you for your time and help!

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { useQuery, gql } from '@apollo/client'
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";

const search_reviews= gql`
 query SearchReviews ($my_query: String) {
    reviews (filters: {title: {contains: $my_query} }) {
      data{
        id
        attributes{
          title
          rating
          body
          categories{
            data{
              id
              attributes
              {
                name
              }
            }
          }
        }
    }
  
 }
}

`


export default function Test() {

    const [ query, setQuery] = useState("")
    const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(search_reviews, {variables: {my_query: query}})
    if (loading) return <p>Loading data...</p>
    if (error) return <p>Error fetching data</p>
    console.log(data)

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="ui search">
                <div className="ui icon input">
                    <form onSubmit={e => {
                        e.preventDefault()
                        console.log(e.target[0].value)
                        setQuery(e.target[0].value)
                        e.preventDefault()
                    }}>
                        <input type="text"
                               placeholder="Search IP"
                               className="prompt"
                                />
                        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

            {data.length !== 0 && (
            <div className="dataResult">
                    {data.reviews.data.map(review => (
                        <div key={review.id} className="review-card">
                        <div className="rating">{review.attributes.rating}</div>
                        <h2>{review.attributes.title}</h2>

                        {review.attributes.categories.data.map(c => (
                            <small key={c.id}>{c.attributes.name}</small>
                            ))}

                            <p>{review.attributes.body.substring(0, 200)}... </p>
                            <Link to={`/details/${review.id}`}>Read more</Link>
                            </div>
                            ))}

            </div>
                )}
        </div>
    )
}
```

[image: twice]

Comment: It would be so much faster for people to read the code if you could clean it up and get rid of comments before publishing it here.

Comment: Apologies! I deleted them! Thank you in advance!

Comment: By saying "runs twice", do you mean the ```onSubmit``` function runs twice, or are you referring to your component re-rendering because you update state with ```setQuery(e.target[0].value)```? That'd be expected behavior.

Comment: @maxeth I need to move to retrieve the data `const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(search_reviews, {variables: {my_query: query}})` only at submit when we have the query parameters in the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick!

`const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(search_reviews, {skip: !first,variables: {my_query: query}})`

Answer (score 0):

```
const { loading, error, data } = useMemo(() => {
   if(!query) return {loading: false, error: false, data: [] }


   return useQuery(search_reviews, {variables: {my_query: query}})

}, [query]);
```

does this work?

when your component renders query is empty string you fetch all data, after you hit submit query gets update(state gets updated) so a re-render happens and now query isnt empty so you get filtered data

essentially what you need is to call useQuery only when query actually changes, you could useEffect(but that requires some amount of change in your current code)